# Why am I getting `npm: not found` error when trying to update Wordpress Docker image version?

Tags: node.js, wordpress, docker, npm

That was supposed to be an actual question that I did struggle with, but I managed to resolve it

So, the thing is: I have a dockerized Wordpress site with Node.JS and NPM. Dockerfile looks like that:

```
FROM composer:2.5.8 as composer
FROM wordpress:6.2.0-php8.1-apache

# ...

RUN apt-get update \
    && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_20.x | bash - \
    && apt-get install -y unzip nodejs jq \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN npm install && npm run build
```

Trying to update Wordpress core 6.2.0 to 6.2.2 - getting an error:

```
 > [stage-1 9/9] RUN npm install && npm run build:
0.224 /bin/sh: 1: npm: not found
------
Dockerfile:36
--------------------
  34 |     
  35 |     # Compile SCSS
  36 | >>> RUN npm install && npm run build
  37 |     
--------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

## SOLUTION

Turned out that docker image of Wordpress 6.2.2-apache and Node.js 17.x is somehow incompatible, but there is two solutions:

1. `wordpress:6.2.1-php8.1-apache` image is compatible with Node.JS 17.x
2. `wordpress:6.2.2-php8.1-apache` image is compatible with Node.JS 18.x
   So, there is two options, but instead of one dependency update I'm obliged to perform two